# What is the solution of the following equation: $y'=\frac y x + \tan \frac y x.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the solution of the following equation:

$$y'=\frac y x + \tan \frac y x.$$

I'm not familar with such equation. I found the solution is $y=x(\arcsin Cx+k\pi)$, however the book gives the answer is $y=x(\arcsin Cx)$. I don't know why?

---

**My Try:**

Let $u=\frac yx$. Then $$xu'+u=u+\tan u.$$

and hence $$\frac{xdu}{dx}=\tan u$$

and hence (if $\tan u$ is not equal to 0, here we may need some discussion)$$\cot udu=\frac1xdx $$
and then $$\ln |\sin u|=\ln |x| +\ln C$$
i.e., $$\sin u=Cx$$

and hence $$\sin \frac yx = Cx$$
So, $$y=x(\arcsin Cx+k\pi)$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whenever you have $y'=F(y/x)$ you can try $y=xz$ as substitution. You will get: $z+xz'=F(z)$ or $xdz/dx=F(z)-z$ or $dz/(F(z)-z)=dx/x$

Comment: @MrYouMath Do we need to discuss when $F(z)-z=0$?

Comment: Yes, you have to consider that. But note that $x=0$ and $y/x=\pi/2+\pi k$, were allready problematic in the original ODE.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=zx\\ { y }^{ \prime  }={ z }^{ \prime  }x+z\\ y'=\frac { y }{ x } +\tan  \frac { y }{ x } \\ { z }^{ \prime  }x+z=z+\tan { z } \\ { z }^{ \prime  }x=\tan { z } \\ \int { \frac { dz }{ \tan { z }  } = } \int { \frac { dx }{ x }  } \\ \int { \frac { d\left( \sin { z }  \right)  }{ \sin { z }  } = } \int { \frac { dx }{ x }  } \\ \ln { \left| \sin { z }  \right| =\ln { C\left| x \right|  }  } \\ \sin { z } =Cx\\ z=\arcsin { Cx } \\ y=x\arcsin { Cx } $$

Comment: Exact but whooo ! If you were a student in Computer Science, I would say "could you comment a little your code" ?

Comment: If $\tan z$ is equal to 0, how could you write as $\frac 1 {\tan z}$?

Comment: $y=x\arcsin { Cx } $ this solution covers inside all infinite solutions so we don't need to write as $y=x(\arcsin Cx+k\pi)$

Comment: @Battani Clearly, $y=k\pi x$ is a solution of this equation, but how could $x\arcsin Cx$ covers it?

Comment: Your solution would be more exactly $y=x\left( { \left( -1 \right)  }^{ k }\arcsin { Cx } +k\pi  \right) ,\quad k\epsilon Z$ ,but in this case we have two parameters that give us infinite solutions,if there were no $"C"$ you would have said right